# In react how to call a function on reaching a specific URL in the browser?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, window.location, location-href

I'm using **window.location.href** to fetch url from the browser. As soon as the specified "url" is reached, it should call the fuction **abc()**, somewhat like below:

```
if (window.location.href === "url") {
  abc(); //calls the function abc
}

function abc () {
  //code..
}
```

How do I do it the right way?

Comment: add `useEffect` hook to your `Component` and run your function inside it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use this

```
useEffect(() => {
 if(window.location.href === 'url'){
  abc()
 }
},[window.location.href])
```

Answer (score 0):

I would make some hook that does that for you. Example:

```
const useAbcHook = () => {
  const location = useLocation()

  useEffect(() => {
   if(location.pathname === "mychoiceurl"){
    abc()
    }
  },
  [url]
}
```

Then to use the hook

```
const MyComp = () => {
  useAbcHook()
  return(<div>....</div>)
}
```